# Unable to load GLSL fragment shader file .frag inside a html

Tags: html, glsl, shader, webgl, fragment-shader

Here is a GLSL `.frag` file and I want to run it inside html.

The `.frag` shader file.

```
// Heartfelt - by Martijn Steinrucken aka BigWings - 2017
// Email:countfrolic@gmail.com Twitter:@The_ArtOfCode
// License Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.

#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_time;
uniform sampler2D u_tex0;
uniform float u_rainintensity;
uniform float u_speed;
uniform float u_brightness;
uniform float u_animate;
uniform float u_rainNormal;
uniform float u_rainZoom;
uniform vec3 u_overlayColor;
uniform float u_islighting; 
uniform float u_pp;
uniform float u_blur;
uniform float u_blurIterations;

#define S(a, b, t) smoothstep(a, b, t)
//#define CHEAP_NORMALS
//#define HAS_HEART
#define USE_POST_PROCESSING

vec3 N13(float p) {
    //  from DAVE HOSKINS
   vec3 p3 = fract(vec3(p) * vec3(.1031,.11369,.13787));
   p3 += dot(p3, p3.yzx + 19.19);
   return fract(vec3((p3.x + p3.y)*p3.z, (p3.x+p3.z)*p3.y, (p3.y+p3.z)*p3.x));
}

vec4 N14(float t) {
    return fract(sin(t*vec4(123., 1024., 1456., 264.))*vec4(6547., 345., 8799., 1564.));
}
float N(float t) {
    return fract(sin(t*12345.564)*7658.76);
}

float Saw(float b, float t) {
    return S(0., b, t)*S(1., b, t);
}


vec2 DropLayer2(vec2 uv, float t) {
    vec2 UV = uv;
    
    uv.y += t*0.75;
    vec2 a = vec2(6., 1.);
    vec2 grid = a*2.;
    vec2 id = floor(uv*grid);
    
    float colShift = N(id.x); 
    uv.y += colShift;
    
    id = floor(uv*grid);
    vec3 n = N13(id.x*35.2+id.y*2376.1);
    vec2 st = fract(uv*grid)-vec2(.5, 0);
    
    float x = n.x-.5;
    
    float y = UV.y*20.;
    float wiggle = sin(y+sin(y));
    x += wiggle*(.5-abs(x))*(n.z-.5);
    x *= .7;
    float ti = fract(t+n.z);
    y = (Saw(.85, ti)-.5)*.9+.5;
    vec2 p = vec2(x, y);
    
    float d = length((st-p)*a.yx);
    
    float mainDrop = S(.4, .0, d);
    
    float r = sqrt(S(1., y, st.y));
    float cd = abs(st.x-x);
    float trail = S(.23*r, .15*r*r, cd);
    float trailFront = S(-.02, .02, st.y-y);
    trail *= trailFront*r*r;
    
    y = UV.y;
    float trail2 = S(.2*r, .0, cd);
    float droplets = max(0., (sin(y*(1.-y)*120.)-st.y))*trail2*trailFront*n.z;
    y = fract(y*10.)+(st.y-.5);
    float dd = length(st-vec2(x, y));
    droplets = S(.3, 0., dd);
    float m = mainDrop+droplets*r*trailFront;
    
    //m += st.x>a.y*.45 || st.y>a.x*.165 ? 1.2 : 0.;
    return vec2(m, trail);
}

float StaticDrops(vec2 uv, float t) {
    uv *= 40.;
    
    vec2 id = floor(uv);
    uv = fract(uv)-.5;
    vec3 n = N13(id.x*107.45+id.y*3543.654);
    vec2 p = (n.xy-.5)*.7;
    float d = length(uv-p);
    
    float fade = Saw(.025, fract(t+n.z));
    float c = S(.3, 0., d)*fract(n.z*10.)*fade;
    return c;
}

vec2 Drops(vec2 uv, float t, float l0, float l1, float l2) {
    float s = StaticDrops(uv, t)*l0; 
    vec2 m1 = DropLayer2(uv, t)*l1;
    vec2 m2 = DropLayer2(uv*1.85, t)*l2;
    
    float c = s+m1.x+m2.x;
    c = S(.3, 1., c);
    
    return vec2(c, max(m1.y*l0, m2.y*l1));
}

    //random no.
    float N21(vec2 p) {
        p = fract(p*vec2(123.34, 345.45));
        p += dot(p, p + 34.345);
        return fract(p.x*p.y);
    }

void main()
{
    vec2 uv = (gl_FragCoord.xy-.5*u_resolution.xy)/u_resolution.y;
    vec2 UV = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;//-.5;
    vec3 M = vec3(0);// iMouse.xyz/iResolution.xyz;
    float T = u_time+M.x*2.;
    
    #ifdef HAS_HEART
    T = mod(u_time, 102.);
    T = mix(T, M.x*102., M.z>0.?1.:0.);
    #endif
    
    
    float t = T*.2*u_speed;
    
    float rainAmount = u_rainintensity;//0.5;//iMouse.z>0. ? M.y : sin(T*.05)*.3+.7;
    
    float maxBlur = mix(3., 6., rainAmount);
    float minBlur = 2.;
    
    float story = 0.;
    float heart = 0.;
    
    #ifdef HAS_HEART
    story = S(0., 70., T);
    
    t = min(1., T/70.);                     // remap drop time so it goes slower when it freezes
    t = 1.-t;
    t = (1.-t*t)*70.;
    
    float zoom= mix(.3, 1.2, story);        // slowly zoom out
    uv *=zoom;
    minBlur = 4.+S(.5, 1., story)*3.;       // more opaque glass towards the end
    maxBlur = 6.+S(.5, 1., story)*1.5;
    
    vec2 hv = uv-vec2(.0, -.1);             // build heart
    hv.x *= .5;
    float s = S(110., 70., T);              // heart gets smaller and fades towards the end
    hv.y-=sqrt(abs(hv.x))*.5*s;
    heart = length(hv);
    heart = S(.4*s, .2*s, heart)*s;
    rainAmount = heart;                     // the rain is where the heart is
    
    maxBlur-=heart;                         // inside the heart slighly less foggy
    uv *= 1.5;                              // zoom out a bit more
    t *= .25;
    #else

    float zoom = -cos(T*.2)*u_animate;
    uv *= (.7+zoom*.3)*u_rainZoom;

    #endif
    //UV = (UV-.5)*(.9+zoom*.1)+.5;
    
    float staticDrops = S(-.5, 1., rainAmount)*2.;
    float layer1 = S(.25, .75, rainAmount);
    float layer2 = S(.0, .5, rainAmount);
    
    
    vec2 c = Drops(uv, t, staticDrops, layer1, layer2);
   #ifdef CHEAP_NORMALS
        vec2 n = vec2(dFdx(c.x), dFdy(c.x));// cheap normals (3x cheaper, but 2 times shittier ;))
    #else
        vec2 e = vec2(.001, 0.)*u_rainNormal;
        float cx = Drops(uv+e, t, staticDrops, layer1, layer2).x;
        float cy = Drops(uv+e.yx, t, staticDrops, layer1, layer2).x;
        vec2 n = vec2(cx-c.x, cy-c.x);      // expensive normals
    #endif
    
    
    #ifdef HAS_HEART
    n *= 1.-S(60., 85., T);
    c.y *= 1.-S(80., 100., T)*.8;
    #endif
    
    //float focus =  mix(maxBlur-c.y, minBlur, S(.1, .2, c.x));
    vec3 col = texture2D(u_tex0, UV+n).rgb;//, focus).rgb;
    vec4 texCoord = vec4(UV.x + n.x, UV.y + n.y, 0, 1.0 * 25. * 0.01 / 7.);

    if(u_blurIterations != 1.0)
    {
        float blur = u_blur;
        blur *= 0.01;
        float numSamples = u_blurIterations;
        float a = N21(gl_FragCoord.xy)*6.2831;
        for (int m = 0; m < 64; m++) {
            if(m > int(u_blurIterations))
                break;
            vec2 offs = vec2(sin(a), cos(a))* blur;
            float d = fract(sin((float(m) + 1.)*546.)*5424.);
            d = sqrt(d);
            offs *= d;
            col += texture2D(u_tex0,  texCoord.xy + vec2(offs.x,offs.y)).xyz;
            a++;
        }
        col /= numSamples;
    }
    
    #ifdef USE_POST_PROCESSING
    t = (T+3.)*.5;          // make time sync with first lightnoing
    if(int(u_pp) >= 1)              
    {           
        float colFade = sin(t*.2)*.5+.5+story;
        col *= mix(vec3(1.), vec3(.8, .9, 1.3), colFade);   // subtle color shift
    }
    float fade = S(0., 10., T);                         // fade in at the start
    
    if(int(u_islighting) >= 1)      
    {                   
        float lightning = sin(t*sin(t*10.));                // lighting flicker
        lightning *= pow(max(0., sin(t+sin(t))), 10.);      // lightning flash
        col *= 1.+lightning*fade*mix(1., .1, story*story);  // composite lightning
    }

    col *= 1.-dot(UV-=.5, UV)*u_pp;                         // vignette
                                                
    #ifdef HAS_HEART
        col = mix(pow(col, vec3(1.2)), col, heart);
        fade *= S(102., 97., T);
    #endif
    
    //col *= fade*u_overlayColor;   // composite start and end fade
    #endif
    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(col*u_brightness, 1);
}
```

The `html` file where it was imported.

```
<script src="js/GlslCanvas.js"></script> 

<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden">
    <canvas 
    id ="WebglOut"
    class="glslCanvas" 
    data-fragment-url="shaders\heartfelt.frag" 
    style="position: absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;" 
    />    
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

 window.onload =()=>{
  let canvas = document.querySelector('.glslCanvas');
  canvas.setAttribute("width",window.innerWidth);
  canvas.setAttribute("height",window.innerHeight);
}


function livelyPropertyListener(name, val)
{
    switch(name) {
    case "blurIntensity":
      glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_blur",val/100);
      break;
    case "blurQuality":
      if(val == 0)
      {
        glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_blurIterations",1);
      }
      else if(val == 1)
      {
        glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_blurIterations",16);
      }
      else if(val == 2)
      {
        glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_blurIterations",32);
      }
      else if(val == 3)
      {
        glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_blurIterations",64);
      }
      break;
    case "rainIntensity":
      glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_rainintensity",val/100);
      break;
    case "rainSpeed":
      glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_speed",val/100);
      break;
    case "brightness":
      glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_brightness",val/100);
      break;
    case "rainNormal":
      glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_rainNormal",val/100);
      break;
    case "rainZoom":
      glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_rainZoom",val/100);
      break;
    case "overlayColor":
      tmp = hexToRgb(val);
      glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_overlayColor", tmp.r/255, tmp.g/255, tmp.b/255);
      break;
    case "imgSelect":
      glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_tex0",val);
      break;
    case "animateChk": 
      if(val == true)
      {
        glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_animate",1.0);
      }
      else
      {
        glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_animate",0.0);
      }
      break;
    case "lightningChk":
      if(val == true)
      {
        glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_islighting",1.0);
      }
      else
      {
        glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_islighting",0.0);
      }
      break;
    case "postProcessingChk":
      if(val == true)
      {
        glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_pp",1.0);
      }
      else
      {
        glslCanvases[0].setUniform("u_pp",0.0);
      }
      break;
    case "fpsLock":
      if(val == true)
      {
        responseTime = 33;
      }
      else
      {
        responseTime = -1;
      }
      break;     
  }
}

function hexToRgb(hex) {
  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
  } : null;
}

</script>
```

Now, the problem is when I tried to load this `html` inside a browser it is just dark nothing else was there. Note that I am aware of the `CORS` policy and ran a local server to serve the `html` file.

All the code I have pasted above are from this link https://github.com/rocksdanister/shadertoy-heartfelt

Comment: What is this `data-fragment-url`, how is it supposed to work ? Where is GL context initialization ? Either you use a new syntax ultra-simplified that I am not aware of, or you are missing a lot of thing...

Comment: In the code they tried to load the `.frag` in a canvas with a `javascript` library and from there `data-fragment-url` filed is coming. Here is the link to that library https://github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/glslCanvas

Comment: Ok... I don't know this library, but seem your problem is around what happen with this library, check the documentation again or contact developers.

Comment: I tried to contact the developer but no response hence I posted. Since, I am dealing with `glsl` file for the first time. Would like to tell me is there any way I could run it in the simple html without that library? Any resource how to load them in the browser will be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, the short answer is a bit rude : Learn WebGL... To load and run GLSL you have to create WebGL context, then use WebGL functions to build the proper program and environment to runs and control that GLSL program. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fact that this is far from valid HTML (which my browser still miraculously manages to render), your actual problem is that apart from `u_time` and `u_resolution` all other uniforms remain unset, most prominently the `u_tex0` uniform that actually specifies the image the shader is supposed to work with, failing to specify this results in the black background (as can be seen when unsetting the texture on the original shader toy), with a texture specified the next pitfall is probably `u_brightness` being initialized to `0`, overall you need to provide some sane/working default values for the uniforms.